# Google Safe Browsing with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I was trying to do some test with Google Safe Browsing Lookup API.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.get("https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/api/lookup",  { client: "api", appver: "1.5.2", apikey: "MYAPI123", pver: "3.0", url:"www.ianfette.org"  } )

   .done(function(data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
  });
});
```

But i cannot get a response from the server. I have tried with fopen in php and it works but i need it to do with jQuery and also to get the response code from the server for example 200 if the site is listed.

Maybe you can suggest and any PHP Solution.

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: An example of the GET URL: https://sb-ssl.google.com/safebrowsing/api/lookup?client=demo-app&apikey=12345&appver=1.5.2&pver=3.0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fianfette.org%2
The fields that you have to have are app, apikey, pver, and url.

Answer (score 1):

$.get does an ajax request, which means that it is limited by the same origin policy, so you cannot access google.com from your domain.

To get around this, you probably need to implement a proxy url in php on your domain and request that with jquery.